# Installing Axis, Tomcat eclipse on a Mac

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-axis, tomcat7, axis

I am having trouble creating a Axis, Tomcat (`apache-tomcat-7.0.27`), Eclipse project.

**note: I am using a Mac OSX 10.7.3**

I have downloaded and installed Tomcat, in eclipse successfully. [I followed the following tutorial](http://www.banym.de/eclipse/install-tomcat-with-eclipse).

Now the problem is to integrate Axis. I downloaded Axis (version `axis2-1.6.2`). And copied the `axis2-web` folder from `......./Documents/AXIS_Project/axis2-1.6.2/webapp` and pasted it in 
the `/Documents/AXIS_Project/apache-tomcat-7.0.27` folder in Tomcat.

Now i restarted Tomcat, and typed `http://localhost:8080/axis2-web/`, then i get the following message;

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 14 in the generated java file
Only a type can be imported. org.apache.axis2.Constants resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: 15 in the generated java file
Only a type can be imported. org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContext resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: 16 in the generated java file
Only a type can be imported. org.apache.axis2.description.Parameter resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: 17 in the generated java file
Only a type can be imported. org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: 18 in the generated java file
Only a type can be imported. org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportListener resolves to a package
```

Comment: How did you start tomcat ? If you start from eclipse, the default config is the minimal one and miss some stuff.

Comment: It tried running tomcat from the terminal as well `./startup.sh`, and  typed `http://localhost:8080/axis2-web/` still i see the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [download page](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/download.cgi), You should dowload the WAR Distribution, not Binary Distribution. The binary need extra steps to deploy. The WAR works just putting it in.